# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientX')

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning! Im trying to move some figures while im moving the cursor, i dont know why this is not working since I did the same on other page and it works:

```
const scaleFactor = 1 / 20;


function movebackground(event) {
    const shapes = document.querySelectorAll(".shape")

    const x = event.clientX * scaleFactor;
    const y = event.clientY * scaleFactor;

    for (let i = 0; i < shapes.length; ++i) {
        const isOdd= i % 2 !== 0;
        const boolInt = isOdd ? -1: 1;

        shapes[i].style.transform = `translate(${x * boolInt}px, ${y * boolInt}px)`
    }

    console.log(shapes)
}

movebackground()
```

I tried another ways to solve it but still with the same issue

Comment: In the example above movebackground is called without a parameter although movebackground accepts the actual event to be passed as first parameter. Thus, event is undefined, which causes the TypeError mentioned in the title.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? How are you wanting to drive the new coordinates? Calling `movebackground()` without an event kind of voids the whole thing. What should drive moving the background?

Comment: It's weird cuz in another project I put the same code and it works now its not working. But basically what I want is that each time I move the cursor the figures translate their positions a bit of the opposite side of the path.

Comment: Sounds like you need an event listener for `mousemove`.

Comment: Obviously can't tell by username, but I'm a lady.

Answer (score 1):

you are invoking `movebackground()` with no parameters which is the same as `movebackground( undefined )`, that's why the error message